# Is there a post processor or similar thing in MicroFocus Load Runner Just like in JMeter?

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

I need a post-processor like function to run a script after the sampler is ran. I previously used JMeter and there was a post-processor function however, I am unable to find a similar function in LoadRunner. Is there anything similar in Loadrunner that I can use to run post condition response?
What I need is to extract the response of one request in an action and pass that value to another request in the same action. These requests are run simultaneously.

```
web_url("PriceStrikeThroughDynamicKitDisplayCmd_2", 
    "URL=https://{host_perf_store}/PriceStrikeThroughDynamicKitDisplayCmd?usertype=&storeId=10151&catentryId=3074457345619656318&skus=8MR32AV%2C8MQ84AV%2CX7B43AV%2CX9H42AV%2C8MR54AV%2C8MQ93AV%2C8MR38AV%2C8MR45AV%2C8MS55AV%23ABA%2C8MR05AV%2C8MR11AV%2C8MR04AV%2C8MR06AV%2C8MR03AV%2C8MQ73AV%2C8MS52AV%23ABA%2C8MS63AV%23ABA%2C8MQ80AV%2C8MS47AV%23ABA%2C9EQ24AV%2C9NA60AV%2C3E755AV%2C4SS11AV%23ABA&crossSell=&currentDate=Mon07Sep202017", 
    "Resource=0", 
    "RecContentType=text/html", 
    "Referer=https://{host_perf_store}/ConfigureView?catalogId=10051&langId=-1&storeId=10151&urlLangId=&catEntryId=3074457345619656318&quantity=1", 
    "Snapshot=t33.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML",
```

I need to extract the response from this request and pass it to another request:

```
web_url("PriceStrikeThroughDynamicKitDisplayCmd_3", 
    "URL=https://{host_perf_store}/PriceStrikeThroughDynamicKitDisplayCmd?usertype=&storeId=10151&catentryId=3074457345619656318&skus=8MR32AV%2C8MQ84AV%2CX7B43AV%2CX9H42AV%2C8MR54AV%2C8MQ93AV%2C8MR38AV%2C8MR45AV%2C8MS55AV%23ABA%2C8MR05AV%2C8MR11AV%2C8MR04AV%2C8MR06AV%2C8MR03AV%2C8MQ73AV%2C8MS52AV%23ABA%2C8MS63AV%23ABA%2C8MQ80AV%2C8MS47AV%23ABA%2CY4S94AV%2C9EQ24AV%2C9NA60AV%2C3E755AV%2C4SS11AV%23ABA&crossSell=&currentDate=Mon07Sep202017", 
    "Resource=0", 
    "RecContentType=text/html", 
    "Referer=https://{host_perf_store_hp_com}/ConfigureView?catalogId=10051&langId=-1&storeId=10151&urlLangId=&catEntryId=3074457345619656318&quantity=1", 
    "Snapshot=t36.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML", 
    LAST);
```

Comment: what if you write a bash script that first executes LoadRunner afterward run any post functions?

Comment: @theshemul I need to run scripts in between the request. I need to extract a response from one of the request and pass it to another request as a parameter

Comment: The term you are looking for is, "correlation."  This capability has existed in every version of LoadRunner produced.   Please refer to the correlation functions in the help system for examples on how such functions are used.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the response handling functions provided by LoadRunner, e.g. [web_reg_save_param_ex](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/lr/en/2020.2.0/help/function_reference/FuncRef.htm#FuncRef/web/lrFr_web_reg_save_param_ex.htm%3FTocPath%3DWeb%2520Vuser%2520Functions%2520(WEB)%7CAlphabetical%2520List%2520of%2520Web%2520Vuser%2520Functions%7C_____41), web_reg_save_param_regexp, web_reg_save_param_json and web_reg_save_param_xpath. Examples can be found via the help center link.